# Get rotating widget degree with GestureDetector

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I want to create knob widget so users can rotate it forward and backward(reverse). I've managed to make it work by using GestureDetector. The only problem is how to know the knob position, I've tried that code but it not working and every time the results are different.

```
GestureDetector(
  onPanUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
    final Offset center = Offset(constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2);
    final offset = details.globalPosition;

    // Calculate the angle in radians
    final double radians = math.atan2(offset.dy - center.dy, offset.dx - center.dx);

    // Convert radians to degrees
    final double degrees = radians * (180 / math.pi);

    // Handle the calculated degrees (update UI, perform actions etc.)
    print("Angle: $degrees degrees"); // Every time the results are different
  }
),
```

Comment: still, same problems

Comment: this should work: `final double radians = (offset - size.center(Offset.zero)).direction`

Comment: Still same results, lets say i have 3 colors on the wheel, sometimes the green show 15 degree, sometimes the blue shows 15 degree, how can I know the color like that?

Comment: sorry, I have no idea what colours you are talking about

Comment: Lets say i build a fortune wheel, how to know which color selected?

Comment: check here: https://gist.github.com/pskink/bc6e9112b52a73df69a2315945758c42#file-rotated_labels-dart-L123 how I calculate `currentAngle` - you can run it directly as it is a complete flutter code

Comment: Thanks, its work as excepted, but I don't know how to use it in my app, I guess I'm just stupid

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the problem is rotationController increase the more i rotate the arrow . What i need is a pie with 3 colors that can be rotated and to know whatever color is on top. If its just increasing i cant know what color is on top, maybe its not about the degree i don't know, anyway, what i really stuck on is to figure what colors is on top

Comment: if you need a pie with 3 colors then change line 41 and add your pie and if you want to know what color is on top then, yes, `rotationController` will tell you as it is an `Animation<double>` so it has `double` value

Comment: But rotationController keep increasing, how can i know what color on top for example when blue on Top is 120 and sometimes 300 and sometime 20

Comment: it is directly used in `RotationTransition` so check `RotationTransition` official documentation on how it uses `turn` parameter

Comment: I've tried that already, still not getting the right results, Anyway i uploaded the full code, I'll be happy if you can take a look https://gist.github.com/alwerr/9388c95f67f3dbd7bf3a829a833bd59a

Comment: That's right, but the problem is, when the user swipe from top to bottom on the wheel, finalAngle increase so if the  purple was between  0.18623485400269946 to
  1.941646470090709, now is between 37.82835337066049 to 39.5859647265776 so i  don't get fixed number to allow me know what current color is below the black cube

Comment: because it rotates the same way if your `finalAngle`  is set to, for example, 0.18623485400269946 or 0.18623485400269946 + 2 * pi or 0.18623485400269946 + 4 * pi etc

Comment: So i could never know what color on top

Comment: That's really cool , Is there a way to know the color while spinning too, not only on end?

Comment: yes, the same way - all depends on `rotation.value` - when you are spinning it changes as well

Comment: your welcome, if you want to know how to detect the color while spinning then check this: https://gist.github.com/pskink/50864143fa9e7c205879048e93365ea8

Comment: Wow, that's really help, thanks again, now I'm struggling making different size for each color, something like pie chart :)

Comment: "now I'm struggling making different size for each color," - check the newest version of my gist

Comment: your welcome, i hope you already figured how the pie division is made (i mean how to define that one segment is wider than another)

Comment: Yeah, your code make it easy to understand, thanks again!

Comment: Can the pie have onTap for each color? For example, when tapping on green color, the green color will be selected and the pie will be rotated so the green color will be on top? I've tried to change some parts of the code but nothing too far

Comment: sure, the latest version has two `IconButton`s per pie to go to prev / next pie

Comment: Yeah that's very cool, thanks. I've tried to change the colors with setState to less colors(lets say from pie of 5 colors to 2) but then the pie get sliced. here's the fork https://gist.github.com/alwerr/6d21e3508cf5d90f2576bfe09eaabc74 . basically the pie needs to stay rounded but with less colors and not get sliced